# how to update syscolumns of a view after alter table - T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, alter-table

Today I noticed when I alter a table which is in a view, the syscolumns of this view is not updated without a run the sp_refreshview. The code bellow show what I'm talking about

```
create table Test ( n1 decimal(12,4) )
go
create view VTest as Select * from Test;
go
sp_help VTest
go
alter table Test alter column n1 decimal(12,2)
go
sp_help VTest
```

Note that VTest stay static, there is someway to automate this process ?

Comment: No, no, no, you don't want to try and update syscolumns yourself (and you shouldn't be using syscolumns or sp_help anymore anyway). Try `sp_refreshview` or `sp_refreshsqlmodule`. Or not using SELECT * in your views in the first place... make them schemabinding so you can't forget to update them *correctly* when you change the underlying table(s).

Comment: PS I have a slide dedicated to exactly this problem in a presentation I give often called "Bad Habits" - using SELECT * in a view is absolutely a bad habit.

Comment: it was just a sample I have not any view with select *

Comment: is there someway to find who is the referenced table in a field view ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `sp_refreshview` to update the view

```
create table Test ( n1 decimal(12,4) )
go
create view VTest as Select * from Test;
go
sp_help VTest
go
alter table Test alter column n1 decimal(12,2)
EXEC sp_refreshview  VTest
go
sp_help VTest
```

Comment: is there someway to find who is the referenced table in a field view ?

Comment: will this help? Select c.text from syscomments c 
join sysobjects o on o.id=c.id
where o.name='Vtest'